# Background shows when appear UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I used this code to choose an image from the library:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{viewLoadPhotoBg.hidden = YES;}];
```

I also use the left menu library in my project. When the UIImagePickerController appears, the left menu shows in background. I guess UIImagePickerController background color is clear and based on my search, some answers say there is no way to change the background color.

What should I do not to see the background when displaying a UIImagePickerController?

Here is the screenshot. I covered my left menu to hide some sensitive information.

[image]

Comment: have some screenshot of the app or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it is really easy. I couldn't figure out yesterday. Here is the  answer;

```
imagePicker.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
imagePicker.view.alpha = 1.0;
```